# specific logs for multiple war having one ear approach

Tags: java, log4j2

specific logs for multiple war having one ear .How to configure the same  using log4j2.xml as i am not able to find any much help in this.i have 5 wars having one ear and when i configure the logs all war logs are printing to only one log file which got loaded first by the class loader.i want my log file to be separate out for each war in single ear.any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [log4j2 log seperation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/logsep.html)

Comment: I already tried that one but its not specifying for multiple war having one ear,its specifying having  one file per ear

Comment: why not using different FileAppender's dedicated to different Loggers dedicated to different wars. for example 3 wars 3 loggers 3 fileappenders. you may choose a way to initialize loggers in base classes for every war. than extend your classes from these base classes

Comment: thats how i have defined it .each war has its own loggers and log4j2.xml files with seperate appenders but the problem is that of loggercontext.each war is changing its context but loggercontext is already registered with first log4j2.xml loggers  so its writing all of my war loggers to in the first log4j2.xml appender.so will you please let me know how to load my  specific log4j2.xml settings wwith repsect to loggercontext  bound to each war on changing the context

Comment: did you tried moving log4j2 jars from ear to war/web-inf/lib for each war. this should work if you have separate log4j2 config files for wars.

Comment: yes this is working but i am not allowed to do so as it will break the whole concept of sharing the resource that is all jars in one place

Comment: ok. then you should keep one log4j2 xml in one of wars (delete others) and define multiple appenders in it.

Comment: But how to differentiate that from which war and from which class in that war i will pick  the respective appenders.

Comment: i will write an answer to your question with a simple approach, you may extend it if you want to use

Answer (score 3):

configuration xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="app4war1" fileName="/logs/war1/app.log" filePattern="/logs/war1/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz" ignoreExceptions="false">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="app4war2" fileName="/logs/war2/app.log" filePattern="/logs/war2/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz" ignoreExceptions="false">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </RollingFile>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="log4war1" level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="app4war1" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="log4war2" level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="app4war2" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

and in your web applications use your own implementaion of LogManager.

```
package myloggermanagerimpl;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class LogManager {

    private static final String prefix = "log4war1.";

    public static Logger getLogger(){
        return org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(prefix);
    }

    public static Logger getLogger(Class<?> clazz){
        return org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(prefix + clazz.getName());
    }

    // and other getLogger() methods in the same manner

}
```

now, you should implement this class in each of your web projects changing `prefix` for each.
then refactor your projects to change `import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;` to `import myloggermanagerimpl.LogManager;`

Comment: Thanks very much sir.you are simply the rockstar.Thats what exactly what i am looking for .really thank you very  much from bottom of my heart

Comment: this will help to all  the guys who are looking for the solution in web